# Rating companies on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: discussion, jobs

Is there a way to rate companies that have posting for positions?

I had a situation where a company scheduled a phone interview, but no call. Sent an email, they called back 2 days later to conduct the phone interview.  I was told that I passed that stage and I was going to get another call more technical.  Again, set up a date, wait for the call, no call. Sent an email,  called me at 10 pm to see if I could do it right now. A bit mad, I did the interview in the worst conditions for me (Playoffs + Beer), but I was tired of their jerking around.

Again, after the call said that they would communicate back and never did. From that point I just quit on that opportunity.  Since the goal of Stack Overflow Careers is to get us our dream job, if the site has companies that aren't up to par, shouldn't there be a way to identify them, so others won't lose their time with them, or at least know what to expect?

Comment: Email the Careers team with the full details and they will hopefully deal with that company.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to rate companies, but FWIW being hungover may affect perceptions of a company.

Comment: @Undo I am under the impression that the interview was *during* a playoff game while beer was being imbibed rather than the morning after with the disappointment of your team's performance (admit it, they're going to get beat by teams that have no snow on the ground at the rink in December) and the hangover casting a shadow over the cognitive facilities.

Comment: @MichealT, yes exactly during the second period, I asked for the call in the morning of that day, because I knew that I wouldn't be concentrated on the interview that night.  I still think a rating system for companies might be good.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear you had a bad experience!

This is a question that we get back to every so often, and that we haven't resolved yet. On the one hand we like the idea of even greater transparency, on the other hand, there are always two sides to a story, sometimes people/companies can just have a bad day, and sometimes people may have different expectations of the process. The fact that a company seems flaky in their recruiting efforts doesn't necessarily mean it's a bad company to work for, it may just mean that their recruiter is overworked. While this is no excuse, making it harder for that company to find programmers would only make the problem worse. And on our end we don't have the manpower to surface the circumstances that may have led to things like this.

So, long story short, we don't have an answer yet, but this is something on our minds, and we'll keep the community posted on any features we might come up with that would facilitate this.

Comment: Again thank for time :D